# Continuous function with a non-removable discontinuity

Tags: calculus

I have the following region  $D=\{(x,y): x^2 \leq y \leq x^2+x^3, x>0\}$. I need to define a continuous and bounded function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is $0$ outside $D$ and with a non-removable discontinuity in the origin. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $x>0$ look for a function of $y$ that is equal to $0$ outside the interval $[x^2,x^2+x^3]$ and positive inside. The simplest one is
$$
(y-x^2)(x^2+x^3-y),\quad x^2\le y\le x^2+x^3.
$$
But it is not bounded. It attains its maximum at the midpoint of the interval. Because of this, define
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{(y-x^2)(x^2+x^3-y)}{x^6},\quad (x,y)\in D.
$$
To see that there is a non-removable discontinuity consider what happens along the curves $y=x^2+\lambda\,x^3$, $0<\lambda<1$.